# array sort on date but is not sorted on time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, sorting

I am sorting an NSMutableArray on my field "date" but it does not take into account the time. If the date is the same, the time is still sorted random. What am I doing wrong? The field "date" is of the type NSDate.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateDescriptor, nil];

[self.player1ScoreT sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

My output is:
2012-11-25 11:01:00 +0000 
2012-11-25 11:00:56 +0000 
2012-11-25 11:00:54 +0000 
2012-11-25 11:01:03 +0000

Strange.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic you're using to sort is correct, I've just tried it and it works fine.

I assume it's because of `[self.player1ScoreT sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];`, this will **not** change the array held in `self.player1ScoreT`, rather, it produces a new array. This is because you're using a selector that will not mutate the original array (`NSArray` itself is not mutable by design, `NSMutableArray` is mutable).

As such, you'll want to use this:

```
self.player1ScoreT = [self.player1ScoreT sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

This will reassign the array within `self.player1ScoreT` to be the new sorted array, produced by `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, and the old unsorted one will be discarded.

Comment: yes youre missing the assignment - overlooked that -- I even tried the sorting myself not believing this :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

As WDUK says, you're missing the assignment of the sortedArray:

```
id newArray = [oldArray sortedArrayUsing...
```

I even tried it and it sorts dates ok INCLUDING time

code I tried:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    id player1ScoreT = @[@{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-100]},
                         @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1000]},
                         @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:+1000]},
                         @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:-50]},
                         @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:+50]},
                         @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:+0]}];
    NSLog(@"%@", [player1ScoreT valueForKeyPath:@"date"]);
    player1ScoreT = [player1ScoreT sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [player1ScoreT valueForKeyPath:@"date"]);
}
}
```